# Differentiating a homogeneous function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I've been working through some problems in my college differential equations textbook, and I've come to one which asks for a proof that if $f(x, y)$ is a homogenous function of degree $n$, then:

$$
x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = n f
$$

I started with the definition of a homogeneous function:

$$
f(tx, ty) = t^n f(x, y)
$$

To get a factor of $n$ somewhere, the obvious thing to try is to differentiate with respect to $t$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(tx) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(ty) & = n t^{n-1} f(x, y)\\
x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & = n t^{n-1} f(x, y)
\end{align}
$$

That's almost in the right form except for that pesky factor of $t^{n-1}$.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Note that in the left hand side you evaluate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx,ty)$. For $t=1$ this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Fix $(x,y)$ and let $g(t) = f(tx,ty).$ There are two ways to compute $g'(1).$